# What type of low-power fan or blower should I use to ensure continuous flow of mist/water vapor into a water bath for studying heat exchange?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, experimental-physics

I plan to perform a lab experiment where a mist generator produces warm mist at a rate of approximately 5-10 liters per hour. This mist will be directed through a pipe to which I wish to attach a device like an ID or FD fan, an air blower, or a propeller. The purpose of this device is to collect the mist and disperse it at a depth of about 20 cm into a water bath, countering the hydrostatic pressure at that depth to maintain a steady flow. This setup is designed to study the direct heat exchange between the warm mist and the cooler water in the bath, leading to the condensation of the mist into liquid form and an increase in the water level of the bath.
However, I'm uncertain about which fan, blower, or propeller to use to ensure the continuous flow of mist into the cold-water bath. In determining the power required by the device to overcome hydrostatic pressure and maintain mist flow, it appears that a device with a relatively low power capacity (around 1-5 W) would be sufficient. I'm seeking advice on where I could find such a device with lower power requirements. Additionally, I would appreciate suggestions on small blowers or compressors available in the market that would suit this experiment. Any feedback or recommendations regarding the design of this experiment would be greatly valued.

Comment: Are you  bubbling misty air into water at a depth of 20 cm?  A diagram would be helpful.